# Get name of private property via reflection without using a string

Tags: c#, reflection

i want to get the name of a private property of a class. 
Reason is i want to set a property of that class that will be obfuscated later. What i have so far is the following:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
    MemberExpression memberExpression;
    var unaryExpression = lambda.Body as UnaryExpression;
    if (unaryExpression != null)
        memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
    else
        memberExpression = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression must point to a Property");

    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

being called like this

```
private static readonly string DisplayNameProperty = ReflectionUtil.GetPropertyName<MyClass>(x => x.MyPublicProperty);
```

The previous example showed usage of the Util with a public property and it works perfectly.
But on a private property it won't work because its private obviously.

Now what will work is:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyPrivateProperty", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .SetValue(_myInstance, true, null);
```

But after being obfuscated the property will not be called `MyPrivateProperty` anymore.

I hope you get my point.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by obfuscating?

Comment: @derape a tool will edit the dll not changing the functionality of it but renaming everything ==> reverse-engineering via decompiling will be almost impossible (everything will be in namespace "A", classes will be called e.g. "fsdklj8439r3" and same for their properties and all variables)

Comment: So can you change the target class?

Comment: @stuartd i dont understand what u mean. Using my Util i can change it, because it gets the property-name on runtime (which will give me "fsdklj8439r3"). But i cant use it on private properties. 
I can't edit the target class itsself, no.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark (since I don't know when the literal will be evaluated), but have you tried using the "nameof" function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) in your "GetProperty"-statement? If the obfuscator is processed before the compilation takes place, you might have a chance :-)

Comment: Since the property is private you can not create a compile time expression targeting it. What you could do is to decorate the property you are looking for with a custom attribute and search that via reflection.

Comment: Hmm... i guess @thehennyy is right probably. I guess your solution would be possible. I have no access to the source code / the class though. So i wont be able to set a custom attribute.
Post as answer and i will OK it

Comment: @MatthiasLoerkeI I didnt try but i guess that will also not work because i cant access a private property?

Comment: If by chance your private property is the only one of its type, you can filter the private properties by their types and gets the one you need. If not, you can still call all the private properties of the right type and look at the results. May be you can determine from the result which one is the good one ? Not a really satisfying solution, but the better I can think of according to your restriction :S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the property is private you can not create a compile time expression targeting it. What you could do is to decorate the property you are looking for with a custom attribute and search that via reflection.

Here is a quick example using a random CustomAttribute:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

public class C {
    [ObsoleteAttribute]
    private string P {get; set;}
}

public class C2
{
    String x = typeof(C)
        .GetProperties((BindingFlags)62)
        .Single(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<ObsoleteAttribute>() != null)
        .Name;
}
```

Comment: Very good solution but the OP says in the comments he cannot edit the source code. I upvoted it because other people with the same problem without the OP restriction will find their solution thanks to you!

Comment: @fharreau you are right. Without changing the original code, the only solution is getting all properties and then try to filter them by type or any other characteristic.

Comment: Unfortunately not a solution for me but still very useful.